# return object from model class

Tags: objective-c, object, nsmutabledictionary

I hope I don't get shaved here!
I try to call a method within my model-class and return a object to the calling controller.

my AppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@class ResultItem;

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>{
    ResultItem *ri;
}
-(void)calculateResults;
@end
```

my AppDelegate.m:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ResultItem.h"

@implementation AppDelegate
    //other stuff

- (void)calculateResults{
    self->ri = [[ResultItem alloc]init];         //ResultItem is my model
    [xx calculateUniformDistribution:(double)x1
            withxMinus:(double)x2
            withxAvg:(double)x3
            withCount:(double)numberCounter];
} ...
```

my ResultItem.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface ResultItem : NSObject

-(NSMutableDictionary *)calculateUniformDistribution:(double)xPlus
        withxMinus:(double)xMinus
        withxAvg:(double) xAvg
        withCount:(int) count;
```

my ResultItem.m

```
#import "ResultItem.h"
@implementation ResultItem

- (NSMutableDictionary *)calculateUniformDistribution:(double)xPlus
        withxMinus:(double)xMinus
        withxAvg:(double)xAvg
        withCount:(int)count{

NSMutableArray *dimensionRandomArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *newResultItem = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

//calculation loop

[newResultItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:max] forKey:@"maxValue"];
[newResultItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:min] forKey:@"minValue"];
[newResultItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:avg] forKey:@"averageValue"];
[newResultItem setValue:dimensionRandomArray forKey:@"randomValueArray"];

return newResultItem;
}
```

The ResultItem method is called fine. I want to create a `NSMutableDictionary` object which I need to handle in my AppDelegate later on.

My Question:

1. How can I access the `newResultItem` within my `AppDelegate` method afterwards.
2. I have no idea how to add more values with keys to the `newResultItem` within my `AppDelegate` method `calculateResults`. Can somebody help me with it please?
3. Who is actually the owner of the `newResultItem` object `ResultItem` or `AppDelegate`?
4. Does it looks wrong to setup the code like this. I try to follow the MVC pattern as best as possible.

Please don't beat me up...

Comment: I think you misunderstood the concept of a model class. Its main use is to encapsulate properties (like xPlus, xMinus...) that you can then access via the appropriate getters/setters.
You can then have some more complex computation inside for some properties (for example if you have a class Circle with a radius property, you can set the perimeter property to return PI*radius*2).

Comment: @Kirualex, I' afraid I still have to learn so much. Thanks for the answer. It helped me a lot with understanding the model. So, if I follow you comments right I would need to put the calculation as an additional method in my controller class, right? I like your picture by the way.

Comment: You can follow @nanako answer which is basically the model you are trying to implement.I don't think you need to defer your calculation in another class if it's meaningfull for your model though (like the perimeter example in my first comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest getting rid of the ResultItem class. I would replace it with a method in controller class instead - in your case, move the calculateUniformDistribution method to the AppDelegate. Or at least move the calculateUniformDistribution to a proper Model class (the actual objects that your app is dealing with Cars, Buses, Airplanes whatever).

As regards actually returning a dictionary and adding values, here is a simplified example, assuming you stick to your current pattern:

In AppDelegate.m

```
self.ri = [[ResultItem alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* dict = [self.ri calculateUniformDistribution:(double)x1
        withxMinus:(double)x2
        withxAvg:(double)x3
        withCount:(double)numberCounter];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:1.0] forKey:@"additionalKey"];
```

In ResultItem.m

```
NSMutableArray* dimensionRandomArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* returningDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

//calculation loop

[newResultItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:max] forKey:@"maxValue"];
[newResultItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:min] forKey:@"minValue"];
[newResultItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:avg] forKey:@"averageValue"];
[newResultItem setValue:dimensionRandomArray forKey:@"randomValueArray"];
[dimensionRandomArray release];

return newResultItem;
```

Notice the autorelease of returningDict and release of dimensionRandomArray. Also, you have to release self.ri afterwards. And if you want to keep the dict around in the AppDelegate, you have to add retain-release.

Comment: I've learned already that I need to think about my concept and I'm not going to stick with my shitty concept. Anyway, I like to see how a "call method return value" over another class work. Nice. I'll check that out but not sticking with that concept, I cross my heart!

Answer (score 1):

Ideally your ResultsItem  should only encapsulate properties and no calculation methods. here is a simple example (to add more values you can use a dictionary like this):

```
   @implementation  ResultItem  
   @synthesize max, min, ...;     
   - (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
      if ((self = [super init])) {
          self.max = [dictionary objectForKey:@"maxValue"];
          self.min = [dictionary objectForKey:@"minValue"];
          ......
                     }
      return self; 
    }
    @end
```

next I would create a Calculation class where you do all your calculation methods, create the ResultItem object like this

```
ResultItem *resultItem = [[ResultItem alloc] initWithDictionary:yourDictionary];
```

and return this object to your AppDelegate.

Comment: why do I need to synthesize `max`, `min ...` when these values get set by the dictionary key-values?

Comment: In order to access the  properties you need to declare the properties in .h like this: `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSNumber* max;`. to create the setter and getter for these properties you need to @synthesize them (@synthesize creates them automatically). maybe its best to make a tutorial like this http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/learn-objective-c-day-4/ as i am not as good in explaining :)